# $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log n}{na_n^2}$ for a sequence $a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms

I am given a nonnegative sequence $a_n$ such that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n = 0$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}na_n^2 \rightarrow \infty$$

Such a sequence is called a moderate sequence i.e. it goes to 0 but not too fast. I am now interested in the limit

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log n}{na_n^2}$$

L'Hospital's rule results in terms with $a'_n$ which I do not know how to handle. Is there anything that can be said about this limit or does it depend on the choice of $a_n$?

Comment: $a_n=c\sqrt{(\log n)/n}$ for any $c>0$. You can also make it go to $0$: $a_n=\sqrt[3]n^{-1}$, or to $\infty$: $a_n=\sqrt[4]{\log(n)}/\sqrt n$.